# Navigation for PDF inside <object> tag

Tags: html, pdf, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `<object>` tag to display PDF on my web page. Weather there is an option to add a **Previous and Next Button** For navigate each page in PDF.

I have googled this issue but haven't found any solution.

```
<object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1000">
  <p>Click Here TO <a href="myfile.pdf"> Download PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

Any other plugins available

Comment: Are you need to add navigation button inside pdf application??

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible

Comment: Yes i need to add a navigation button

Comment: Any plugins, jquery available